# Use wsse soap locally

Tags: java, php, soap, wsse

I have a problem of internet slowness and cutoff so I want to use the

```
wsse soap file oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
```

locally instead of using the link:

```
http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Save it into your local machine and use :)

Comment: Create a new project for that put your files there and run that project locally and then use it.